# ffmpeg convert images to mp4 error

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, imagemagick

So I have a script that grabs a bunch of images from the web and then converts them into a movie. Yet I get a whole bunch of errors when I run it.

First let me show what I am running and then I will post the error because it's huge:

```
#for gif
#call('convert -set delay 5 -loop 0 ' + folder + '*.jpg ' + name + '.gif', shell=True)
#for mov
#call('convert -quality 100 ' + folder + '*.jpg ' + name + '.mov', shell=True)
#for organized movie
call('ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i ' + folder + '%0' + str(size) + 'd.jpg ' + name + '.mp4', shell=True)
```

So the commented out versions work fine, but I need to use the 3rd version! Here is the response I get from ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 21:55:33 with Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libfreetype --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff5a680ae0] Picture size 10835x53928 is invalid
    Last message repeated 26 times
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cf)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c8)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff5a680ae0] Picture size 54310x53928 is invalid
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] only 8 bits/component accepted
    Last message repeated 8 times
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c5)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff5a680ae0] Picture size 10835x53928 is invalid
    Last message repeated 12 times
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cf)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] only 8 bits/component accepted
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cf)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] only 8 bits/component accepted
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cf)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] only 8 bits/component accepted
[image2 @ 0x7f8cc4029c00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 0x7f8cc4029c00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
/Users/ryansaxe/Desktop/kaggle_parkinsons/MOVIES/%03d.jpg: could not find codec parameters
```

Note: `[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cf)
[mjpeg @ 0x7f8cc402a800] only 8 bits/component accepted` repeated about 30 times, but i cut it out of the traceback because it was overwhelming.

**Question: What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?**

Edit:

I download the jpeg files using the urllib python library's [urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib#urllib.urlretrieve). This is how I save them:

```
for src,name in zip(urls,range(len(urls))):
    file_name = folder + str(name) + '.jpg'
    urlretrieve(src, file_name)
```

Comment: print the line before using `call`. You are probably passing something wrong to ffmpeg. BTW, change `-b 1800` to `-b:v 1800K` or remove it

Comment: which line? the one that call is using?

Comment: FFmpeg seems unhappy with the JPEG files. Are you sure they're valid? Are they all sequential? Can you decode them with other software?

Comment: hmmmm Well yes they are sequential, and I need to download with python because it is for some open source code. I just posted how I download the images if you think that could be it...

Answer (score 0):

First, add the line:

```
print('ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i ' + folder + '%0' + str(size) + 'd.jpg ' + name + '.mp4')
```

right before `call`.

Second, run this line from the shell. Debug from there.

Subdividing problems helps.